# Output text with hyperlinks

Tags: c#, .net, ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

If you have text coming from a database such as:

```
 "New Apple TV Offers 8 GB of Internal Storage, 256 MB RAM http://t.co/fQ7rquF"
```

Is there a helper method that takes that text and wraps the web address as a anchor tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head I would run a regular expression to match a link pattern and throw the anchor tags around it.

Found [this](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/PrintSearchContent.asp?LINKID=423) on google:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions; 

public string ConvertURLsToHyperlinks(string sInput) 
{ 
    return Regex.Replace(sInput, @"(\bhttp://[^ ]+\b)", @"<a href=""$0"">$0</a>"); 
}
```

It looks for "http://" followed by anything that's not a space, separated by word boundaries.

Comment: This will work in the example stated in the question, but many URLs in the real world end in a slash (`/`) or other punctuation characters and your regex wouldn’t match that.

Comment: This didnt work actually. I copied the RegEx from the link Kevin gave and that worked - Regex.Replace(sInput, @"(\bhttp://[^ ]+\b)", @"<a href=""$0"">$0</a>");

Comment: @Timwi - how can we modify the Regex to fix it?

Comment: @Timwi - it seems fine with a slash on the end

Comment: @Jon: No, it doesn’t. It doesn’t linkify the slash. (And other punctuation characters.)

Comment: Well spotted. How can we fix this?

Comment: adding the literal `"` to the `[^ ]` group should take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

i believe there is no such helper method but u can create one

```
public static class helper{
public static string AnchorHelper(this htmlHelper helper, string text)
{
   //here u can use kevin's function to generate anchors
   return ConvertURLsToHyperlinks(text);  
}
}
```

you have to add corresponding namespace in ur view and then u can just use it like other html helpers

```
<%=Html.AnchorHelper(TextwithUrls)%>
```

Comment: The class needs to be marked `static` for extension methods to be permitted in it.